# Image Segmentation

Tags: image, segmentation

I have what should be a pretty simple question for Mathematica gurus. I have a set of images containing cars and a background. I am trying to create a black and white image where the white part is the car and the background is black. I am linking a sample input image and what the output should be. Thanks in advance.

input= https://s3.amazonaws.com/albertoaiml/car.jpg

[image]

output = https://s3.amazonaws.com/albertoaiml/outputcar.png

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Neural Net Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/tasktype/Semantic-Segmentation/) has several useful Neural Nets and examples of exactly this type of problem.

Using one of the Neural Networks is quite easy. The first time you evaluate a NetModel, it downloads a fairly large amount of data from the internet. I'll use the [Ademxapp Model A1 Trained on ADE20K Data](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/Ademxapp-Model-A1-Trained-on-ADE20K-Data) since that's one I already have downloaded.

First, we set up a function to deal with reshaping the input and output. Basically, the network has been trained on images of a certain size and type, so this function changes whatever image you give it into the size and type the network expects.

```
netevaluate[img_, device_: "CPU"] := 
 Block[{net, resized, encData, dec, mean, var, prob}, 
  net = NetModel["Ademxapp Model A1 Trained on ADE20K Data"];
  resized = ImageResize[img, {504}];
  encData = Normal@NetExtract[net, "Input"];
  dec = NetExtract[net, "Output"];
  {mean, var} = Lookup[encData, {"MeanImage", "VarianceImage"}];
  prob = NetReplacePart[
     net, {"Input" -> 
       NetEncoder[{"Image", ImageDimensions@resized, 
         "MeanImage" -> mean, "VarianceImage" -> var}], 
      "Output" -> Automatic}][resized, TargetDevice -> device];
  prob = ArrayResample[prob, Append[Reverse@ImageDimensions@img, 150]];
  dec[prob]]
```

Then, we create a list of labels, one for each class that the neural network knows about. This is in the documentation for each Neural Network.

```
labels = {"wall", "building", "sky", "floor", "tree", "ceiling", 
   "road", "bed", "windowpane", "grass", "cabinet", "sidewalk", 
   "person", "earth", "door", "table", "mountain", "plant", "curtain",
    "chair", "car", "water", "painting", "sofa", "shelf", "house", 
   "sea", "mirror", "rug", "field", "armchair", "seat", "fence", 
   "desk", "rock", "wardrobe", "lamp", "bathtub", "railing", 
   "cushion", "base", "box", "column", "signboard", "chest", 
   "counter", "sand", "sink", "skyscraper", "fireplace", 
   "refrigerator", "grandstand", "path", "stairs", "runway", "case", 
   "pool", "pillow", "screen", "stairway", "river", "bridge", 
   "bookcase", "blind", "coffee", "toilet", "flower", "book", "hill", 
   "bench", "countertop", "stove", "palm", "kitchen", "computer", 
   "swivel", "boat", "bar", "arcade", "hovel", "bus", "towel", 
   "light", "truck", "tower", "chandelier", "awning", "streetlight", 
   "booth", "television", "airplane", "dirt", "apparel", "pole", 
   "land", "bannister", "escalator", "ottoman", "bottle", "buffet", 
   "poster", "stage", "van", "ship", "fountain", "conveyer", "canopy",
    "washer", "plaything", "swimming", "stool", "barrel", "basket", 
   "waterfall", "tent", "bag", "minibike", "cradle", "oven", "ball", 
   "food", "step", "tank", "trade", "microwave", "pot", "animal", 
   "bicycle", "lake", "dishwasher", "screen", "blanket", "sculpture", 
   "hood", "sconce", "vase", "traffic", "tray", "ashcan", "fan", 
   "pier", "crt", "plate", "monitor", "bulletin", "shower", 
   "radiator", "glass", "clock", "flag"};
```

Now we can create a mask that segments all the objects in the image (that is, all the objects the neural network is able to see).

[image: Input to generate mask]

You can visualise this mask easily by using `Colorize`, and you can easily get a list of all the items the neural network can see with `labels[[DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@mask]]`.

[image]

Now that we have this mask, we can get rid of all the classes that aren't the object you're looking for - in this case, cars.

We first find the index of the object we're looking for in the labels.

```
index = Position[labels, "car"]
```

In the case of this network, it's `21`.

Now we set all the pixels in the mask to be 0 unless they have the value `21`. (This isn't great code, sorry!)

```
ReplaceAll[{21 -> 1, _ -> 0}] /@ # & /@ mask
```

[image: Mask]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Wow, this is great. Thank you so much. I will mark this question as answered.

Comment: Just one quick correction, if you want to edit your answer. I think the last step should be: Colorize[ReplaceAll[{21 -> 1, _ -> 0}] /@ # & /@ mask]

Comment: `Colorize` will display an image in more or less the same way that `Image` will, if `mask` is a list of zeroes or ones, so either would be correct :) In any case, `mask` can be used in many ways, not just for display - for instance you could make a word cloud of different translations for "car" in the shape of the mask :) Check the Neural Net Repository for many other examples of how to do this - your mileage will vary with different nets.