# Distinguishing different cars in picture

Tags: image, segmentation

I recently posted a question. And I got a great answer from Mr. Carl Lange

[Image Segmentation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/171606/image-segmentation)

His solution worked like a charm. However, I got another request which is more generic in nature. The request is to be able to pick out the foreground car and eliminate background cars. The test picture input picture is this

[image: Input]

And the result I am currently getting is this:

[image]

But it should be more like this:

[image]

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In other words, the background cars should be filtered out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's an undocumented function called `ImageContents` that will give you bounding boxes for various objects in your image. (This likely is some nice wrappers over the [YOLO V2 network](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/YOLO-V2-Trained-on-MS-COCO-Data_1) which you could use directly.)

[image]

First we set up a quick getCarMask function from [the previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/171606/image-segmentation):

```
getCarMask[img_] := 
 Map[# /. {21 -> 1, _ -> 0} &, netevaluate[img], {2}]
```

If you know that the car you care about is going to be the biggest car, do something like:

```
imask=SetAlphaChannel[img,mask]
```

where the mask is the above mask

```
ImageContents[imask][
 Select[#Concept == Entity["Concept", "Auto::p735c"] &]][
 First, "Image"]
```

to get the largest "car" bounding box.

From here you could, for instance, attempt to re-run the original answer's method on this smaller section, or do some other processing to get a better answer - doing `EdgeDetect`,`ImageSaliencyFilter`, and `GrowCutComponents` might be a good place to start. Hope that helps, sorry it's not a drop-in answer - hopefully a decent starting point though.

I stress that you could probably get the same/similar result without using the undocumented `ImageContents` by using the YOLO V2 network.

Comment: Carl, you are a rock star. Thanks.